# Adding controller to app.js gives a blank page

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I want to add controllers to my app. But while add a controller the browser displays a blank page.

Here is routing:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('Login', {
        url: '/Login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/Login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .state('SignUp', {
        url: '/SignUp',
        templateUrl: 'templates/SignUp.html',
        controller: 'SignUpController'
    })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Login');
});
```

Here is my controller

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.controller('LoginController',function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup) {
$scope.showAlert = function() {
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Success',
    template: 'Mobile Number Verified',
  });
  alertPopup.then(function(res) {
    console.log('Thanks');
  });
 };
});
```

How to make the controller work?

Comment: You'd need to inject $scope, $state and $ionicPopup in your LoginController. They seem not to be injected, only referenced.

Comment: how is it supposed to be done?

Comment: angular.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicPopup', function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup) {
/* ... rest of code ... */
}]);
By adding dependency on $scope, $state and $ionicPopup BEFORE your controller will do that.

Comment: Change `angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])` to `angular.module('starter.controllers')` in your controller file and you don't have a controller defined for `SignUpController` which I know for definite will give you a blank screen!

Comment: @sarker306 I would also recommend this, but it is only done to avoid problems after code minification. Injection should work anyway.